# docker swarm maintain communication with phyical hosts

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I have a 7-node docker swarm which successfully runs my application. The problem that I have is that I have to laptops that are not part of the swarm (and shouldn't be) that need to maintain communication with the message bus in the swarm.

Meaning the laptop has to be able to communicate with the physical host that hosts the message bus container in the swarm. The problem is that if that system goes down the message bus will be started on a new machine and the laptop cannot communicate with the message bus.

Any thoughts ? Ideas ?

Comment: you've opted out of using swarms ingress routing mesh?

Comment: @ChrisBecke I am confused and that is probably because of a gap in my knowledge. Can you explain further ? Is there a way for the laptops to communicate using ingress routing mesh w/o being in the swarm ?

Comment: when a service on docker swarm exposes a port, it is exposed on all swarm nodes by default. docker swarm implements an overlay network for ingress traffic and routes all traffic to the correct nodes where services instances are running.

Comment: Understood. However, the two laptops are not part of the swarm. Both laptops are windows OS and, for some reason, making those laptops part of the swarm did not seem to work. Right now, I have a 7-node swarm (linux) and two laptops.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve by making the laptops part of the swarm. if code on the laptops needs to access the message queue, then publish the message queue ports, and get the laptops to access <any-swarm-ip>:<mq-port>

Comment: I have a GUI (laptop, not on swarm) that accesses the message bus (on swarm). Everything will work fine but in the event the swarm node hosting the message bus goes down and the message bus is deployed to a new node one the swarm I will lose connectivity to the message bus because it will have moved to a new host with a new IP.

Comment: This is what the ingress network solves. You connect to any swarm node - it doesn't matter which node the mq is on.

Comment: so, as long as I know all the nodes in the swarm I can retrieve data from mq ?

Comment: you only need to know one swarm ip.